# iOS app in a zombified state

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app

iOS app 1.4.3, iOS 9.2.1

While viewing a post, the app somehow ended up in a state where it refuses to do much of anything.

What *does* work:

- Swipe-scrolling vertically
- Jumping to the previous / next post using the up / down buttons

Everything else, though, has no effect:

- Swipe-scrolling horizontally will not return to the previous view
- Tapping on a code block will not zoom to code-block view
- Tapping <kbd>Delete</kbd> button to delete a post will show a confirmation dialog, but saying yes will not cause deletion
- The <kbd>Add Comment</kbd> button brings up the text field, but I cannot type anything in it; I can only dismiss it
- None of the other buttons (<kbd>Share</kbd>, <kbd>More</kbd>, etc.) do anything
- Cannot view user profiles or revision history
- Tapping on links in a post or comment will not show a web page
- Tapping on a tag shows some visual feedback with a temporary color change, but doesn't do anything else

I still receive push notifications, but tapping on them doesn't take me anywhere.

Comment: Repro'd. Looks like things constrained to the current view controller work but anything involving another view controller fail. Maybe the result of an unbalanced transition? I'll try again on Monday when I can hook to a debugger.

Comment: Killing the app did get me back to a usable state.

Comment: I've been frantically tapping everything I can trying to reproduce this again with no success. I'm going to keep a lookout for it but if you notice any actions that reproduce this state, it'll be helpful.

Comment: I accidentally created a duplicate of this issue — maybe it needs a more descriptive name, so it can be found via search?

Comment: @Toadfish Feel free to edit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will be fixed in 1.4.4.1, shipping early March.

It appears the SFSafariViewController swipe gesture in 9.2 breaks the view transitioning state. [This should also be fixed in 9.3](https://twitter.com/rmondello/status/694442723332329472).

I'll also be applying [this fix from the Apple forums](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/29048#discussion-105377) for users still on 9.2:

```
SFSafariViewController *viewController = [[SFSafariViewController alloc] initWithURL:URL];
viewController.delegate = (id)delegate;

// There was a major bug in 9.2 where SFSafariViewController's swipe gesture broke the view controller hierarchy.
// This fix comes from https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/29048#discussion-105377
if (SEIsAtLeastIOSVersion(9, 2) && !SEIsAtLeastIOSVersion(9, 3)) {
    viewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationOverFullScreen;
    UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController];
    navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
    return navigationController;
} else {
    return viewController;
}
```

Comment: Verified fixed in 1.4.4. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Apologies for posting an answer but I don't have enough rep to post a comment.

The action that causes this behavior is a swipe in from the left to return to a question after following a link that opens the in-app browser.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Wait what? You've got 101 rep... :)

Comment: Took a while to figure this out, but I just had an answer upvoted on another site, which bumped me to 200 rep on that site, which got me the "trusted" bonus of +100 rep on all sites. It's all in the timing, I suppose. :)

Comment: The association bonus is a lovely thing, isn't it :)

Comment: Just confirmed the same reproing http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315887/cant-go-back-to-question-list. Good catch.